# In C#, How can I get ALL the messages out of an Azure Service Bus Queue?

Tags: c#, message-queue, bulk, azure-servicebus-queues, receiver

Because I need to remove duplicate messages and delay processing some messages which are "too new" (as determined by the most recent copy of a message), I want to handle the entire contents of Service Bus Queue all at once.

I'm not sure how many messages I can expect, but I feel strongly optimistic that it shouldn't normally be in the hundreds, never mind that thousands which I *thought* could be the limit for `ReceiveAsync (int maxMessageCount, TimeSpan operationTimeout)`.  However, it turns out that no matter how high that value is, I'm only able to read about 30 to 50 messages in a single invocation of

```
        private async Task<IList<MicrosoftMessage>> Receive(IQueueConfig queueConfig) =>
                await _messageReceiverLookup.GetMessageReceiver(queueConfig.QueueName)
                    .ReceiveAsync(queueConfig.MaximumRecords, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

I tried wrapping this with some additional logic, like:

```
            List<MicrosoftMessage> messages = new();
            List<MicrosoftMessage> newMessages = new();
            do
            {
                newMessages = await ReceiveMessages(queueHandler, cancellationToken);
                messages.AddRange(newMessages);
            }
            while (
              newMessages.Count > 0 
              && messages.Count > 0 
              &&  messages.Count < queueHandler.QueueConfig.MaximumRecords
            );
```

But discovered this never ends because the system will read the same message multiple times.

So then I tried this:

```
          Dictionary<string, MicrosoftMessage> previosMessagesByToken;
            Dictionary<string, MicrosoftMessage> allMessagesByToken = new();
            List<MicrosoftMessage> newMessages;
            do
            {
                previosMessagesByToken = allMessagesByToken;

                newMessages = await ReceiveMessages(queueHandler, cancellationToken);
                Dictionary<string, MicrosoftMessage> newMessagesByToken = newMessages.ToDictionary(x => x.SystemProperties.LockToken, x => x);

                // Ensure we only collect each message once!
                allMessagesByToken = allMessagesByToken.Concat(newMessagesByToken.Where(kvp => !allMessagesByToken.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)))
                    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
 }
            while (
                    newMessages.Count > 0
                    && allMessagesByToken.Count > previosMessagesByToken.Count
                    && allMessagesByToken.Count < queueHandler.QueueConfig.MaximumRecords
                );
```

This seems to work, but on the one hand, I have a gut feeling this should not be so complicated.  Also, I don't entirely trust this since I do not entirely understand why I don't get all the messages nor why I get duplicate messages, so I can't help feeling that somehow this algorithm could allow some messages to fall between the cracks, being a non-duplicate that is not included.

Is there better way I can make get all the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few foundational assumptions:

1. Number of the requested message is not guaranteed to be the number of delivered messages.
2. Messages received in `PeekLock` mode will have their lock expired at some point and will be delivered.

If your objective to drain all the messages, you should either complete the messages you've received or receive in `ReceiveAndDelete` mode. That way you won't get the same messages again. If you trying to peek at the messages in the queue, then your `LockDuration` would need to be long enough to ensure all messages have peeked.

> I need to remove duplicate messages and delay processing some messages which are "too new" (as determined by the most recent copy of a message), I want to handle the entire contents of Service Bus Queue all at once.

The bigger issue seems to be the attempt to handle messages in the queue like records in a database. Duplicate detection is already a feature of Azure Service Bus. Deferring messages as well. But it would require a different approach than batch processing.

Comment: There is logic I need to execute to determine whether messages should be Completed, Abandoned, or DeadLettered, so I probably need to do something with the LockDuration, but I think this may somehow be preventing me from Completing messages?  I saw there is something about duplicates detection, but couldn't figure out how I can supply logic for what defines a duplicate.  Also, I need conditional logic for which messages to defer, so I don't know whether that could help me....

Comment: Messages are deduplicated base on message ID. I wrote a [post ](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/bend-message-deduplication-on-azure-service-bus-to-your-will) about that. Maybe it will help you. The message disposition (completion, deferral, abandoning) is not prevented by lock duration. Lock duration is literally the lease time. Long story short, I strongly recommend to get away from a batched approach. It will only benefit you. If you need message sessions, that's a different story. But don't force a queue to become a DB. Use DB instead.

Comment: I need to deduplicate based on content, not message id, but I'll check your blog.  Thanks.

Comment: That's what the post is showing. Read l, then reply  Cheers.

Comment: if I can get the sender to play ball (probably), it might help, but my use case is slightly more complicated.  I'm expecting the sender to send many duplicates, but I only want to take action on the last one, as determined by when it was sent, after some period of time (e.g. 5 minutes) has elapsed.  So I would need the duplicate detection to preserve the timestamp on the last message received, not the first or any between.

Comment: That sounds like a workflow you should really consider reviewing. Why there are duplicates and action should be taken on the last message within a span of some time? Are those truly "duplicates" if the action is only taken for the last message? And what happens if a duplicate arrives 5 mins and 10 seconds? What does it mean to process a duplicate? Don't think SO will be a good source of the answer. If those messages are truly duplicates and can be safely ignored, process the first message and have deduplication on the rest based on the maximum time frame.

Comment: If the messages are not the same and the last message in the series does have something unique (based on time or the message data) then it requires a different approach. One that likely requires a state. Either a message session or something with a "memory element" such as saga (using [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/) or [MassTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/)) would be an option. Again, I don't have the full context of the problem at hand.

Comment: In a nutshell, we have an application which generates a message for the service bus whenever the user does something.  If the same user does that something, the message should have identical content.  We want the service bus to do something with the message only when the user has stopped doing the activity (as determined by a period elapsing without us receiving additional messages).  For reasons I'm not entirely aware of, it is too complicated to have the system which will send the message reliably figure out when to send the final message and spare us the previous messages.

Comment: That's interesting... you are having a non-deterministic problem here. How do you know that the user has stopped? What if the user clicks ten times in a row and then waits for 3 minutes and then clicks for the 11th time? I'd rather go with idempotent message handling. I.e. see if the message (ID based on content or some other identifier) has been already handled. If it was, the receiver discards the message w/o processing father. That's a much more realistic way of solving this kind of problem than trying to wait until the user is done messing around.

Comment: We consider the user stopped after 5 minutes.  That's considered "good enough", even if it might on occasion prove false.   We need to wait till he/she is finished before we take further action.

Comment: I've seen these kinds of assumptions biting in the rares later. Assumptions change. 5 minutes could be "oopsie, it took 5m10s". In this case, what I'd do is have a state for the operation (assuming it could be uniquely identified) and updated the state until a timeout (5 minutes or whatever is configured). Similar to what can be done with Durable Functions in Azure. A [Timer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=csharp) would control at what point an operation is executed with the most recent set of changes for the given operation ID.

Comment: Cheers for the additional feedback.  In this use case, the timeout period is something we can configure outside of the code, so we can make an adjustment if it turns out to be too short.  Also, what eventually needs to happen involves Salesforce which has many terrible limits, so the concern is not precisely or just whether an individual message is exactly 5 minutes old, but rather to collect a bunch of unique messages which are all at least 5 minutes old and then work with them collectively.